# CSS - Font won't import from local ttf file?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Ok, I think this may have to do with the font-family name I am giving my font imports, but for some reason only Proxima nova light will load. The others don't register when I use them in my css.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "ProximaNova";
    src: url(fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.ttf");

}
@font-face {
    font-family: "ProximaNova-Light";
    src: url(fonts/proximanova-light-webfont.ttf");

}
@font-face {
    font-family: "ProximaNova-Bold";
    src: url(fonts/proximanova-bold-webfont.ttf");

}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham";
    src: url(fonts/GothamBook.ttf");

}
```

For all, I have my fonts in a folder called fonts in my css folder where the css script lives. If I try to use `font-family: 'proximanova'`however  it does not work -

I am referencing the right file name:
[image]

And I made up the font-family names (just to something that made sense), however I don't think this should matter as my light proxima nova is loading. 
Why won't my fonts work?

Comment: Write your font name the same way you declared it. Try `body { font-family: "ProximaNova"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the opening `"` in your url.

So change

`url(fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.ttf")`

to

`url("fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.ttf")`

Also, check you have the right file permissions set.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

Make sure each file and the directories have correct permissions set.  And that the files are not symlinks or anything like that.

IT also looks like your missing the first quotation mark in the url